# issue with hive partitioning and bucketing in CDH 5.10 quick VM

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am new to this area and got stuck in a simple issue.

I am loading data into a hive table (using insert command from another table tset1) which is partitioned by udate and day as bucket.

```
insert overwrite test1 partition(udate) select id,value,udate,day from tset1;
```

so now the issue is when I am loading data it is taking wrong value in partition column. Day is taken as partition because in my table this is last column so during data load it's taking day as udate.

how I can force my query to take the right value during data load?

```
hive (testdb)> create table test1_buk(id int, value string,day int) partitioned by(udate string) clustered by(day) into 5 buckets row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

hive (testdb)> desc tset1;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
id                      int                                         
value                   string                                      
udate                   string                                      
day                     int 

hive (testdb)> desc test1_buk;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
id                      int                                         
value                   string                                      
day                     int                                         
udate                   string                                      

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

udate                   string 

hive (testdb)> select * from test1_buk limit 1;
OK
test1_buk.id    test1_buk.value test1_buk.day   test1_buk.udate
5   w   2000    10
```

please help.

Comment: "I am loading data..." - how? What is your Hive version?

Comment: using insert query. I am using Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.10.0

Comment: Present a clear scenario with clear example: source table DDL + source data, target table DDL, INSERT statement into the target table based on the source table how the the target table data looks after the insert.